# Question on an IVP

Tags: calculus

Consider the in initial value problem $$y’=\sin{(y+t)}+e^t-\sin{(e^t+t)}, \quad y(0)=2.$$ One of the following things is true:

1. $y(t)>e^t$ for all $t\in I$.
2. $y(t)<e^t$ for all $t\in I$.
3. Neither 1. nor 2.

State which is true and justify your answers.

Well we know that a unique solutions exists according to the existence and uniqueness theorems centered around $0$. Also we know that $|\sin{(x)}| \leq 1$ which means that 2. must be true.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: But $y(0) = 2 > 1 = e^0$.  What is $I$?

Comment: Great thank you so much. $I$ is some interval $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $0\in I$.

Comment: Then the problem becomes trivial since by continuity, in any  small enough interval containing $0$  $y(t)>e^t$.

Comment: Great thank you.